# Google Chrome Extension Can't See Clicks?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener

I can't get any of these event listeners to trigger any functions.

The below is in my chrome extension.   The alert is triggered but none of the listeners work.   The elements are created dynamically so I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('.overlay_show').addEventListener('click', alertit);
    document.querySelector('.overlay_hide').addEventListener('click', alertit);
});
```

element html

```
`<a class='overlay_hide' ><i>Hide<i/></a>`;
```

`

Any ideas would be helpful?

Comment: `The alert is triggered but none of the listeners work.` that seems to be contradictory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The elements are created dynamically so I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

It does. If you add the listener *before* you add the elements, it won't work. When you do `document.querySelector('.overlay_show')`, it selects the first element that has the class `.overlay_show`, and adds a listener upon it. **Done**.

So, you have 2 solutions:

#### Add the listener *after* you add the element

But it means that you have to do that *each* time you do so

#### Listen for a click on `<body>` and use `e.target`

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('overlay_show')
        || e.target.classList.contains('overlay_hide')) {
        alertit()
    }
}
```